# How could I rebountify the question that did not get any answers?

Tags: support, bounty

How could I rebountify the question [How do I troubleshoot unresponsive UI in SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75556700/how-do-i-troubleshoot-unresponsive-ui-in-swiftui) that did not get any answers raising the bounty?

Comment: Wait for the bounty grace period to clear (another 24 hours), then raise a new bounty. It'll have to be 100 points or more this time.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't post a new bounty on your question until the previous bounty process has ended.

The previous bounty is *still active*, it is currently in the 24 hours grace period phase. You can post a new bounty once that phase has ended. You could use the time to review your question again to make sure it has all the information needed to answer it, see the [*How do I ask a good question* help information](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Please note that a new bounty must be at least 2x the previous bounty amount, so at least 100 points.

Comment: 2x? I thought it only had to be 50 more. Does that mean a bounty of 300 can't be renewed?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel FYI, the network Meta FAQ [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/16067) states, in the third paragraph of the "Can I offer a second bounty after the first one has expired? / Can I raise my bounty?" section, that "If you've already offered a bounty for 250 or more reputation, you can still offer more bounties for 500 (the maximum amount) as long as you like (or as long as you have the rep)."